# Valid SQL Server Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, odbc, inner-join

During batch processing, there seems to be an occasional '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] run-time error thrown.

I believe this to be caused by an invalid INNER JOIN statement in the legacy code causing undefined behavior. Would the following query be valid for SQL Server 2016? Should it be checking for NULL values?

```
Declare @UseUCASE int = 0
select
 @UseUCASE = case T1.item_val_txt
 WHEN 'Y' then 1
 else 0
 end
from table1 T1
join table2 T2 on T2.item_id = T1.item_id
where item_key_txt = 'letters.key'
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated to include entire code snippet

Comment: Bearing in mind that you are using an ODBC connector to run the query, are you sure the problem is not with the code behind this query? This is not an sql server error, but an ODBC error

Comment: Your code includes a variable but it is not defined and the context of execution is not provided. Most likely, as already suggested, the application is at fault and causing the error when certain runtime conditions are encountered. Debugging "occasional" problems can be difficult without instrumentation and logging. Beware using SELECT as a shortcut for a scalar assignment